# Fbprophet error 'Series' object has no attribute 'nonzero'

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to implement a Time Series Forecasting using FBProphet.

The data is of `one year` of `daily frequency` and has 2 columns: `Date` and `Daily Total Time`

My code is:

```
Date            Total Time
317 3/19/2020   495.256579
318 3/20/2020   312.727632
319 3/21/2020   278.980263
320 3/22/2020   0.000000
321 3/23/2020   153.446053

df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

def positive_average(num):
  return num[num > 0].mean()

daily_data = df.groupby('Date').apply(positive_average)
daily_data.head()

daily_data = daily_data.dropna()


weekly_data = daily_data.iloc[:, (daily_data.isna().sum() <=8).values]
weekly_data = weekly_data.dropna()

from fbprophet import Prophet
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

df = weekly_data.reset_index()
df.columns = ['ds', 'y']
df.head()

       ds            y
0   2019-03-01  124.813158
1   2019-03-04  154.826316
2   2019-03-05  628.684211
3   2019-03-06  690.492105
4   2019-03-07  719.939474

prediction_size = 30
train_df = df[:-prediction_size]

model = Prophet()
model.fit(train_df)
```

This `model.fit()` method is throwing the following error:

```
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-014bed53c8b5> in <module>()
  1 model = Prophet()
----> 2 model.fit(train_df)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py in fit(self, df, **kwargs)
776         history = self.setup_dataframe(history, initialize_scales=True)
777         self.history = history
--> 778         self.set_auto_seasonalities()
779         seasonal_features, prior_scales = (
780             self.make_all_seasonality_features(history))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py in set_auto_seasonalities(self)
637         last = self.history['ds'].max()
638         dt = self.history['ds'].diff()
--> 639         min_dt = dt.iloc[dt.nonzero()[0]].min()
640 
641         # Yearly seasonality

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
5275 
5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nonzero'`
```

Any reason where I am going wrong or any issue with the code?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Note:
`Python Version:  3.6.5`

`Pandas Version: 1.0.3`

`Numpy Version: 1.18.2`

`Fbprophet Version: 0.2`

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my Fbprophet version. It was 0.2. I updated it to 0.6 and that solved the issue.